# I am getting the error NoMethodError in CarController#add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
NoMethodError in CarController#add

undefined method `user_id=' for #<Car:0x7160c70>
RAILS_ROOT: C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2
```

add.html (for adding car)

```
<h1>Ask a Question or Discuss Your Car</h1>
<%= error_messages_for :car %>
<br>
<p>You can ask anything related to cars even if its not a Mercedes!</p>
<% form_for :car do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name, "Title of Question" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description, "Describe Your Question" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

def add in car_controller.rb:

```
def add 
      @title = "Ask a New Question"
    if request.post?
       @car = Car.new(params[:car])
       @car.user_id = User.logged_in(session).id
    if @car.save
        flash[:notice] = "Car #{@car.name} added!"
        redirect_to :controller => :car, :action => :index
      end
    end
  end
```

car.rb model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :subject
  validates_presence_of :name, :description
end
```

routes.rb

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.resources :car, :users => { :delete => :get }
  map.root :controller => "main"
  map.root :controller => "car", :action => "destroy"
end
```

create_cars migration:

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.interger :user_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :cars
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your car model & migration look like?

Comment: Can you post your database schema?  That error typically means that there is no user_id field.

Comment: @ jared hales @Tom I have posted it now

Comment: @ jared hales @Tom I have posted it now

Comment: any ideas anyone? deadline in 1 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors:

1. `user_id` is declared as an "inte **r** ger"
2. I think you meant to write `user =` rather than `user_id =`

Answer (score 1):

Chuck is correct.  Your user_id is declared as an "interger".  Consider using

`t.references :user` 

instead of `t.integer :user_id`.

Also verify that your user model declares it's connection to the car model using has_one or has_many.

If `User.logged_in(session)` returns a User model object, you can do `@car.user = User.logged_in(session)` If not your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know how is relation defined in your User model, might be you not defined the relation in User model due which its not able to find the user_id